# Setting the label and value size for axis in PCA plot with fviz_pca_ind in factoextra

Tags: r, pca

im using `fviz_pca_ind` function in `factoextra`.
What i cannot accomplish is to set the size of the axis labels and values + the size of the legend.

```
    fviz_pca_ind(mydata.pca, repel = TRUE, alpha.ind = 1,
+              habillage = mydata_attributes$attribute1, # color by groups
+              palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"),labelsize = 5, pointsize = 1, font.family = "Arial",
+              addEllipses = TRUE # Concentration ellipse
+ )
```

i just found how to set the size of my samples and the points.
Could somebody help me?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `factoextra` library relies on `ggplot2` to draw its plots. So you can append it with `ggplot2::theme()` function to customize the plot attributes. In your case a possible solution would be:

```
fviz_pca_ind(...) +
  theme(
    legend.text = element_text(size = 20),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 15)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

- try `font.x = c(10,"plain","black"), font.y =  c(10,"plain","black")` for axis labels and `font.xtickslab = c(9,"plain","black"), font.ytickslab =  c(9,"plain","black")` for axis annotations. See [ggpar](https://rdrr.io/cran/ggpubr/man/ggpar.html) for more values you can adjust within fviz-functions
- legend text is a bit tricky though. I used `ggtheme = theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 10), legend.text = element_text(size = 9))` for this